# liquibase exception for class casting throwable can not be casted to exception

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, liquibase, changelog, liquibase-hibernate

Error Looks Like Following

```
[2024-02-08 10:57:43] INFO [liquibase.command] Command execution complete
[2024-02-08 10:57:43] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] class java.lang.Throwable cannot be cast to class java.lang.Exception (java.lang.Throwable and java.lang.Exception are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Throwable cannot be cast to class java.lang.Exception (java.lang.Throwable and java.lang.Exception are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:253)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:55)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:24)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$execute$2(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:391)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:195)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:171)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$execute$3(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:366)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:195)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:171)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.execute(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:363)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.main(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Throwable cannot be cast to class java.lang.Exception (java.lang.Throwable and java.lang.Exception are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.logPrimaryExceptionToMdc(CommandScope.java:287)
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:245)
    ... 18 more
Unexpected error running Liquibase: class java.lang.Throwable cannot be cast to class java.lang.Exception (java.lang.Throwable and java.lang.Exception are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Throwable cannot be cast to class java.lang.Exception (java.lang.Throwable and java.lang.Exception are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:253)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:55)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:24)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$execute$2(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:391)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:195)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:171)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$execute$3(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:366)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:195)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:171)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.execute(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:363)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.main(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Throwable cannot be cast to class java.lang.Exception (java.lang.Throwable and java.lang.Exception are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.logPrimaryExceptionToMdc(CommandScope.java:287)
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:245)
    ... 18 more
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':diffChangelog
```

build.gradle looks like

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'org.liquibase.gradle' version '2.2.1'
}

//our own config for running liquibase diff
//apply from: 'gradle/liquibase.gradle'
//apply plugin: "org.liquibase.gradle"
group = 'com.prismhr.api'
version = '1.0.0'

java {
    sourceCompatibility 17
    targetCompatibility 17
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.prismhr.api:prismApi-common:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
//    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-tx'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.25.1'
    liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate6:4.25.1"
//    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:2.1.1'
    liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.output
    liquibaseRuntime 'info.picocli:picocli:4.7.5'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
}

//with the new Spring boot version 2.5.4 bootJar and jar was running to create two snapshot version,
// resulting in docker failure, need to specifically set jar to false to make sure to not get SNAPSHOT-plain.jar
jar {
    enabled = false
}

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile "src/main/resources/db/changelog/" + (new Date()).format('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss') + "_changelog.xml"
            referenceUrl 'hibernate:spring:com.prismhr.api.generalledger.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy'
            url "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=myschema&INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS myschema"
            username "postgres"
            password "mysecretpassword"
            driver "liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver"
            logLevel "debug"
        }
    }
}

//configurations.configureEach {
//    exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
//}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

all db details sent in application.yaml are correct i can see this exception whenever I try to run diffchangelog command.
Please help me out.

Comment: please share the complete stacktrace

Comment: same for me after upgrading dependencies to the latest and greatest. However, it only happens in Gitlab CI but works locally on Windows for some reason. I've edited your post and added the stacktrace. Feel free to edit it in case yours is different. I'm using JDK 21, Gradle 8.6 and Spring 3.2.2

Comment: found an alternate solution anybody interested in alternate solution?